# Using CSS to divide text into rows

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

On my wordpress / woocommerce website I have a lot of product options, in my cart where those options are displayed - the options chosen are presented as a fluent text as oppose to have one option per row which would look a lot more structured and would be easier to read.

My question is if its possible, using CSS to structure the fluent text into rows, CSS would be the most convenient way for me to resolve it although I am open to other options as well.

Try adding the following product to cart [LINK](https://www.fonster24.tk/webshop/fonster/trafonster/tra-vridfonster/)
Add to cart button says "LÄGG TILL I KUNDVAGN" on my language.
Then go to [CART](https://www.fonster24.tk/kundvagn/).

As you can see in the first column beneath the title and beside the product image - Type of option in regular text then : and chosen option in bold text.
First two options are "Bredd: **5 (480 mm)** Höjd: **5 (480 mm)**"

What I want is it to be displayed like this instead:

Bredd: **5 (480 mm)**

Höjd: **5 (480 mm)**

Etc.

Is there an easy solution to this problem? Again preferably via CSS?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If you want a good response from users I would recommed you post some code or some images of the problem rather than links to unkown websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you would like all of the items stacked, apply

```
.variation{ 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Perfekt! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` for this. Add following CSS to resolve this issue

```
.tm-cell {  /*Or you can update your selector*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you inspect the html code you can see that the div surrounding the entries is:
    `<div data-uniqid="58ede56aeca6c6.03775072" data-logic="" data-haslogic="" data-fblabelshow="" data-fbvalueshow="" class="cpf_hide_element tm-cell col-6 cpf-type-select prod-height-div">`

It's class width is set to 50%, so you can set it to 100% by adding this to your css:

```
.tm-extra-product-options .col-6, 
.tm-extra-product-options .tm-cell.col-6, 
.tc-cell.tc-col-6, .tc-col-6 {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```